# Visiting UK with European visa

Tags: visas, uk, german-residents

Here is the problem. I have a long-term visa (I live and work in Germany and I'm married). I want to visit London (to be specific, I am from Tunisia).

I heard that having a long-term visa for a European country can make it easier for me to apply for a UK visa (as I saw, the visa is required in my case).

I don't know how I should apply for this visa, and to use my European visa to facilitate the steps.

Comment: `long term visa for an european country, can make it easier for me` Not always. Google for `apply for uk visa` and the 1st link in the result list is where you apply.

Comment: Are you married to an EU citizen? And if so, are you travelling with them?

Comment: Yes my wife is german, my daughter too, and I am going to make holiday with then in London.

Comment: @MoslemCherif in that case you can apply for an EEA family permit, which is free of charge, but this depends on your wife being German rather than on your residence permit.

Comment: It is not clear really ... Currently we are leaving in Germany, and my wife and my daughter have the german passport, how can I apply for this EEA family permit? I want just to travel for 1 week for holidays that is all ..

Comment: "how can I apply for this EEA family permit?": https://www.gov.uk/family-permit/apply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- When a visitor applies for an UK visa, he has to *convince* the UK visa officials that he is not trying to become an illegal immigrant. All other things being equal, a legal resident of Germany will have it easier than a legal resident of, say, Egypt or Mexico, because he is **already** a legal immigrant in a wealthy nation.
- When an EU citizen (like your wife) travels in the EU, she has a right to bring her immediate family with her. For the time being, the UK is still part of the EU. You need a document to cross the border, but it is not called a visa. Here is the German wiki page regarding the [EEA Family Permit](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Economic_Area_Family_Permit).

Comment: Small quibble: "family member" is not necessarily "dependent": in particular, spouses and partners (among others) do not need to prove dependence, while parents, parents in law, and other ascending-line relatives do need to prove dependence.

Comment: @phoog, edited.

Comment: English version of the EEA Family Permit link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Economic_Area_Family_Permit

Comment: Another small quibble: derivative rights can extend to family members who are not immediate family.  :-)